# Implement double click action using macro in excel

Tags: java, excel, vba

I am writing excel sheet using java with values like this `0.11`. Before  `0.11`  value, there are 5 spaces.

I am writing `'` so that value will start from left of the cell. So when I manually perform double click action, that `'` goes away.

That's what i need.

So I thought of implementing double click action using macro on one column, so that `'`goes away.

Please help!

Comment: Why don't you just not put the `'`? If you want the number to be a number and be left aligned, then use the left-align button.

Comment: @JNevill  The problem is , before value i need 5 spaces,so in java there is no way to write values with spaces.
If you know one please tell.

Comment: The problem is, as soon as you remove that `'` it is going to format at is a number and you will lose your spaces again. If you can first format that column (in java) as Text format, then paste in your number with spaces it should go in fine and preserve your spaces.

Comment: @JNevill       Firstly,I donot want to delete `'`.When I double click on it , that symbol will vanish.Secondly, I am formatting value as text before writing to cell.

Comment: @JNevill          Before double click `'      0.11`.  After double click `0.11`

Comment: Then, in that case, don't format it as text and leave the `'    0.11` and the `'` should disappear on it's own. This is just one of those oddball things with excel. Text formatted cells will display whatever you put in them. Non-Text formatted cells will behave like we are used to where a cell value of `'    0.01` shows up as `        0.01` <with spaces>

Comment: @JNevill ,I did try to write value without formatting as text, as well as without adding  `'` symbol. It's working fine, but the problem is if we double click on cell with value, then that value is changing to right alignment.

Comment: Darn. That's quite the problem them. Perhaps, before relying on vba (Which is certainly a possibility) consider writing the value, on a non-text formatted column, from java as `="    0.11"`. If that is acceptably, I would think it would be preferable over VBA

Comment: @JNevill yes, tried that also.Nothing is working that's why i thought of this alternative option.Can you please help with macros double click event?

Comment: @YowE3K It's displayed because the cell is formatted as text before the value is dropped in with the `'`. However, if OP changes the format of the cell to non-text (like General) when OP drops in `'    0.11` java or excel takes that to mean the number `0.11` and the spaces disappear. Ultimately, OP wants to drop `'     0.11` with spaces into the cell and have those spaces preserved, but between Java and Excel OP can't find a way to do it. So VBA to toggle those cells over to General with spaces preserved seems like the only option. (correct me if I'm wrong about any of that, OP)

Comment: `Cells(1,1).Value = "'     0.01"` will successfully insert the text string "     0.01" into the cell.  The same thing should work whether it is Java (using InterOp or whatever it is called) or whether it is straight VBA.  The `'` isn't part of the value stored (i.e. a LEN(A1) would return 9, not 10), so I'm not sure why there is a need to get rid of the formatting `'`.  (It's not displayed, except in the formula bar.)

Comment: Grrr - I hate how HTML drops spaces.   That example was a 0.01 with 5 leading spaces.

Comment: @JNevill - Did I miss something - is the OP formatting the cells as text **before** putting in the number with the `'`, and then formatting back to General?  Just tried with a cell preformatted as text and it performed exactly like one not preformatted.  And I can't get double-click to make any change to the cell.  I think I'm confused - must be time for breakfast.

Comment: Well.. yes formatting as text, dropping in the `'    0.11`, but not formatting back to General (I was going to suggest that next). Currently OP has found that double clicking on the Text formatted cell with the `'` visible causes the `'` to disappear and act (I assume) as a General formatted cell. I think this is because of the way that Java is writing to the application since formatting a cell as text, putting the value `'    0.11` into it and then double clicking the cell does nothing when I try it.

Comment: @mayankbisht - Can you please post the code into the question.  It might allow us to replicate what is happening to you.  (As far as I can see, the `'` shouldn't be visible in the cell, so you shouldn't need to do anything to make it not visible.)

Comment: @JNevill Even if the cell is formatted as text, then has a `' 0.01` placed into it, and then changed format to General, the cell would still contain a number formatted as text.  (Even doing those steps without the `'` leaves the cell with a number formatted as text.)

Comment: **Thanks everyone for providing valuable suggestions** .I tried everything like you said, but nothing worked out. So I starting thinking of way around to this problem and I got one.There is no way to write values with spaces and `'` using java.But using excel macro we can do it.If we write `'     20.00` in excel it will remove `'` from the cell, and also will retain spaces, same principal I have applied in my problem.Now I wrote macro, that will read column with values from excel that are populated using java and it  will write back that value in cell.